# How am I supposed to install mockgen when I am using vendoring?

Tags: go, go-modules

I have a project that is using vendoring.

I need to run mockgen. But I can't use my local install because of the vendoring. Fair enough, I would like to package mockgen into vendor.

However the usual

```
go get github.com/golang/mock/mockgen
go mod tidy
go mod vendor
```

will not do anything unless the package is imported into my code. However, mockgen is not an import, it is a program. And if I try importing it, I get a red squiggly.

Im not sure if it compiles with the red squiggly tho, I did not try.

At least when I import mockgen, go vendors it.

What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: You are right, mockgen is a binary and you can't import it into your project. On linux we can simply install `mockgen` using `sudo apt install mockgen` or `go install go.uber.org/mock/mockgen@latest`. Mock library from Golang is deprecated, you should use the library from Uber.

Comment: After you finished installed `mockgen` into your system, add `mockgen` into your ENV path, sometimes `go install` is not registered into env path. Once it is installed, go to your project directory and execute mockgen like this `mockgen --source path/to/your/file.go --destination path/output/file_mock_test.go --package <package>`

Comment: See "Case 2" in the answer to the linked duplicate.

Comment: 2 things: if you rely on mockgen for unit testing, you will, by definition have imports for the packages (by virtue of its generated mocks + `gomock.NewController(t)` in the tests). You can also mark the interfaces you want to mock with the `//go:generate github.com/golang/mock/mockgen [flags here]` directive. If you want to ensure a module is there, a common trick is to have a blank file in your project that just contains some underscore imports (`import _ "github.com/golang/mock/mockgen"`,

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Just as a note: `go install` is not a solution for me as I am using vendor, and I get this error if I  run it `cannot find module providing package github.com/golang/mock/mockgen/model`. This even though I have mockgen on my path. Also `import _ "github.com/golang/mock/mockgen` is not really allowed since mockgen is a program and not an importable. Though maybe it still will compile, I haven't tried it